# Kafka snappy compression

Tags: apache-kafka

I am a newbie and like to test Kafka with snappy compression. But it doesn’t seem that data is compressed; gzip seems working. Can you please see what can be the reason for this?

I created 3 topics for no, snappy, and gzip compressions.

```
$ kafka-topics.sh --create --topic no-compressed-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
$ kafka-topics.sh --create --topic snappy-compressed-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config compression.type=snappy
$ kafka-topics.sh --create --topic gzip-compressed-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config compression.type=gzip
```

And pushed 1M records to each, for example:

```
$ kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic no-compressed-topic --throughput -1 --num-records 1000000 --record-size 1000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
```

Disk usages:

```
$ du /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/no-compressed-topic-0/ -sh
1001M   /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/no-compressed-topic-0/
$ du /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/snappy-compressed-topic-0/ -sh
1011M   /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/snappy-compressed-topic-0/
$ du /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/gzip-compressed-topic-0/ -sh
630M    /tmp/kraft-combined-logs/gzip-compressed-topic-0/
```

Kafka version is 3.4.0 and there is no change in server.properties. I tested in linux and Mac and they yielded same (very similar) results. Also tested with 18 partitions with more messages and results were similar.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at a hexdump of the actual segment files, not simply comparing disk space. Also ZSTD should be a better compression than the above

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for your input. 
With kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments, as far as I can read, the sizes per record are ~1000, ~1000, and ~640 bytes respectively.
I'd like to see (or profile) how much/fast snappy compresses; not looking for another solution.

Comment: My first thought it that the broker or producer is defaulting to use snappy compression, but that wouldn't explain why the second disk usage is about 10MB / 10% larger

Answer (score 0):

When I used the tpch tool, the data is compressed (getting smaller) with snappy well. I ingested 15M records and disk usages are like under.

```
4.4G    no.customer-0/
1.8G    snappy.customer-0/
1.3G    gzip.customer-0/
```

It seems this is because of how kafka-producer-perf-test.sh generates the record data.

```
SSXVNJHPDQDXVCRASTVYBCWVMGNYKRXVZXKGXTS ...
```

As @OneCricketeer thought, the data might be already snappy compressed. Or the data is structured the similar way that snappy would do so it is not getting smaller.
The tpch tool generated recored data is in JSON text.